# What is the Effective way of Accessing sql database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

In asp.net webform projects we create a connection channel where ever we need to access(insert,update,delete,select) the database which is like more or less as below mentioned.

My thought about this is can we create a class which stores all the queries and the connection string.is this way is correct ? if not what is the professional way ?

```
public bool ValidateFunc(string findText, string findField)//checking whether the mailid or username already exits
        {
            .. .. 
            .. ..
            string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            string seletquery = @"SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE" + findField + "  = @Findt";
            SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(seletquery, Connection);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Findt", findText);
            Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader ad = Command.ExecuteReader();
            .. ..
            .. ..    
        }


public void InsertFunc()//inserting into database 
        {
            string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            string insertq = @"insert into Registration values (@fname,@lname,@dob,@emailid,@uname)";
            SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(insertq, Connection);
            Connection.Open();
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not bundle all DB access into a single class. As your project grows, it will quickly become unmanageable.

One way to go that is widely accepted is to use the Repository pattern.

See this StackOverflow question for more information: [Repository Pattern Step by Step Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985736/repository-pattern-step-by-step-explanation)

This writeup on MSDN is also pretty good:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Comment: Cant we use stored procedure?

Comment: Of course. Your Repository classes can uses whatever they want to access the database. The point is that the database implementation is hidden from the rest of your application. And if you use the Repository pattern with IoC you can also easily unit test your classes that use your Repository class by mocking out your Repositories. See this MSDN article for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx

Comment: I just came across 3 layer architecture. will it be a good one?