# How to take data from databasee using LinQ and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am the beginer of ASP.NET MVC. could you please help me how to unstand simple example to collect and process data from database. 
For Ex:
i have a database with name store with table shoes that have columns: shoes_ID, Shoe_desc, Shoe_Qua
I need to build a small simple website that can display list of shoes and Update, Delete or Edit the shoes.
So what is the code to query to table ( i've already connect string in wedconfig) and show all products shoes to View and acction Updte, Delete and Edit using ASP.NET MVC.
Thank you very much for learning from you!

Comment: Look in tutorials. Use google!

Comment: Sorry i can not give you clearly!only want to show data from data base to website use LinQ and ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 2):

There are many great resources for doing this and there is an abundance of tutorials on youtube or google just ripe for learning.

As a .Net developer I am extremely fond of the IRepository pattern using the .Net Entity Framework, I am not exactly sure your skill level but if you are looking for a simple but extremely solid way of performing CRUD operations I think the IRepository pattern is your best bet. Here are some links to help  you get started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

[Repository Pattern Step by Step Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985736/repository-pattern-step-by-step-explanation).

Take a good look at courses on Pluralsight as well, I have learned so much about ASP and the frameworks it uses by spending hours watching courses. One that really clicked for me was a tutorial by Shawn Wildermuth when he stepped through building an entire website using ASP, EF and a few other frameworks. Here is the link http://beta.pluralsight.com/courses/site-building-bootstrap-angularjs-ef-azure

There are still tons of other ways to do what you're asking, I am speaking strictly from my experiences as I have found nothing better than IRepository and EF.

Comment: For simple crud, a fully blown ORM like EF is not completely necessary. When I am doing just simple CRUD, I use a micro-ORM, such as peta-poco