# Domain driven design methods in aggregate

Tags: c#, .net, events, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

My question is in regards to the following:

If I have a class that manages users, lets call it `UserManager`. Should it be responsible for updating users in the database (something like `RegisterUser`, `UpdateUser` methods which uses a repository interface) in scenarios where a new user *registers* or *updates* profile?

I think this task can be delegated to another class. Something like `UserSubscription` class that handles calls(events) that are related to the `UserRepository`. I imagine this `UserSubscription` class of having methods (lets call them `UpdateUser`, `SubscribeUser`) that recieves `ValueObject` from `UserManager` class and uses them to *update* or *register* users. I think that this `UserSubscription` and `UserManager` classes could be in the same *Aggregate* in the *Application Layer*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html):

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a
>   collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.

A repository's responsibility should be loading / storing / updating users (in a database / other storage) in a generic way. See [Repository Pattern Step by Step Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985736/repository-pattern-step-by-step-explanation) for more details.

If your UserManager does just this, it should be a UserRepository instead. However, if your UserManager's tasks are different, it should use the UserRepository for handling storage of users.